mtp Samsung Smartphone's do not show the name on Nautilus
I have several smartphones connected to Ubuntu 23.10 and Nautilus Files 45.rc.
I cannot change the name shown in the Nautilus side bar, for the Samsung smartphones Nautilus shows "Samsung Android" instead of the Device Names. Interestingly when clicking "Properties" (Sidebar -> right mouse button on a Samsung Android entry -> Properties), the properties dialog shows the given name (the one which can be set on the android "about System").
Any hint how I can change the displayed names in the Nautilus sidebar?
Or how it can be configured that Nautilus shows the Device Name as set on the smartphone?
Thanks!
screenshot shows two Samsung Android instead of their name. Name shows correctly in the "Properties" dialogue.

this explains reputation and then, as for posting images, does this Q&A answer that question?
